# NodeJs: How to view a sqlite databse that is hosted on fly

Tags: node.js, sqlite, deployment, prisma, remix.run

So I have deployed this repository as it says in the readme file.

https://github.com/remix-run/indie-stack

Everything works well and I see that my site is deployed, the question is: How do I view my database that is hosted? I can only see one app got created in fly, so where is my sqlite database living and how to manipulated the live data directly from the tables.

As I have never used the combination of Prisma and Sqlite so It would be great if you provide me some quick tips/ suggestions to learn to use it.

Edit: On the readme file it says
You can connect to the live database by running `fly ssh console -C database-cli`.

but I do not have ssh installed and I get the following error:

Run "flyctl.exe version update" to upgrade.
Connecting to top1.nearest.of.speedshop.internal... complete
Error error connecting to SSH server: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

Is it absolutely necessary for me to have ssh to view my DB or there is another way?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Comment: Windows, I use the basic cmd nothing fancy installed...

Comment: I would like to access the table interface that prisma provides during the development

Comment: You would like to look at your production data similar to how the `npx prisma studio` command shows data, right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want